How do I map a tuple of key/value objects to an object?
In the code block below, how do I rewrite the function keyValueArrayToObject so that keyValueObject is of the type {a: number; b: string}, and not of the type {[k: string]: any} as it is currently?
const arrayOfKeyValue = [
  {key: 'a', value: 1},
  {key: 'b', value: 'z'},
];

const keyValueArrayToObject = <const T extends readonly {key: PropertyKey; value: any}[]>(
  arr: T
) => {
  return Object.fromEntries(arr.map(o => [o.key, o.value]));
};

const keyValueObject = keyValueArrayToObject(arrayOfKeyValue);


"Excuse me for the long code example. I feel like if I don't share the whole context, it will be unclear what I'm trying to achieve." But having over a hundred lines of code obscures this by forcing people to scroll around to see your code. If you can't make a [mre] that fits on a normal size screen at once, maybe your code is too long to be a good Stack Overflow question. I'm almost positive you can whittle this down to something reasonable, though. Please do try to do that.

(see prev comment) "The code blocks in this post can be copied together into your IDE and it will compile." Yes, but the problem you're having should jump out at us when we look at an IDE. So the hope is that some part of it should "not compile", meaning that we see an error where you expect the lack of one. Or some indication, in the example code itself, of what the problem is directly. That makes it easy to test, since if we fix it, your test case code will automatically start working as desired. While you're working on a [mre], please try to put in a test case of this sort.

(see prev comments) I think maybe this approach is what you want, but please please make this example more minimal (there's so much stuff here when all you're looking for is a way to map an array of key/values to an object, and you can do that with like six lines of code, possibly as shown here. The other stuff is mostly distraction and you should be able to connect the dots from a general arr-to-obj code to your root/soil/sap/leaf/branch/xylem thing.) Does that fully address the q and I'll write an answer after you edit? Or am I missing something?

Thank you, the approach works! I edited the original post (based on the example you sent) so that it is much shorter. Thank you again, I will try to do better next time when I describe my problem.

You can use key remapping in mapped types to iterate over the union of the element type of the arr aray, and for each member U of the union, you index into that member for the key and value properties to get the key and value of the mapped property:
const keyValueArrayToObject = <const T extends readonly { key: PropertyKey; value: any }[]>(
  arr: T
) => {
  return Object.fromEntries(arr.map(o => [o.key, o.value])) as
    { [U in T[number] as U['key']]: U['value'] };
};

We need a type assertion because TypeScript doesn't strongly type Object.fromEntries() enough.

Now we can test against your example:
const arrayOfKeyValue = [
  { key: 'a', value: 1 },
  { key: 'b', value: 'z' },
] as const; // <-- need this

const keyValueObject = keyValueArrayToObject(arrayOfKeyValue);
/* const keyValueObject: {
    a: 1;
    b: "z";
} */

That looks good although it's slightly different from what you asked for. First, you need to use a const assertion or something like it on your array literal. Otherwise TypeScript will infer a wide type like Array<{key: string, value: string} | {key: string, value: number}>. That type isn't wrong, but it's not specific enough for your needs. You need the compiler to keep track of the literal types of the key properties at least.
With a const assertion you also get the literal types of the value properties, and hence keyValueObject is inferred to have type {a: 1, b: "z"}. If that's too specific then you'll need to either widen it manually, or take more control over your array literal types, such as [{ key: 'a' as const, value: 1 },{ key: 'b' as const, value: 'z' }] or the more bizarre [{key: 'a', value: 1},{key: 'b', value: 'z'}] satisfies ({ key: "xxx" | (string & {}), value: unknown })[]. But I consider this out of scope for the question as asked.
Playground link to code
